# How to (re)install a driver from an old windows backup ("system image")?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, windows-backup, wifi-driver

I deleted by mistake my Bluetooth driver (by checking the box "delete the driver software" while uninstalling). But I have a recent backup (system image).
How can I reinstall my driver from this backup?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to first browse inside your "system image"** (your windows backup) to copy the driver folders:

1. In start menu: copy "   create and format Hard disk partitions  "
   and open it: this opens "Disk management"
2. Click on menu Action, Attach VHD, browse to your backup drive and
   then a path like
   K:/WindowsImageBackup/USERNAME/backup_xxx(date)xxx/... .vhdx (if
   there are several .vhdx file, you probably need to choose the
   biggest one - the smallest one is probably the recovery partition),
   click open, then click OK
3. In the bottom part, scroll down to the drive that doesn't have a
   letter: right-click on the biggest partition (not the drive, the
   partition), click "change drive letter and path", then "add" then
   "assign"
4. Go to windows+e and select the drive with the letter you choose

**Then you don't need to find the right driver, windows will do it automatically: you only need to point the folder of drivers** (I wasted a lot of time not having this information, by comparing the drivers folders).

**Go to device manager** (run devmgmt.msc), select the hardware/device that needs the driver:

Right click device, update driver, browse my computer, then set the path to the bkp `\\Windows\System32\DriverStore` [if it doesn't work, try the other folder:  `\\Windows\System32\drivers` and then  `\\Windows\System32\DriverState`].
Let windows find the driver.

In my case, Windows found the driver but put a warning symbol on my Bluetooth device (on the device manager). But it despairs after a few minutes (windows solved the issue, the BT driver was working).

**When it's done you can unmount the system image** (it's not a big deal as it will detach itself at the next reboot): go back in "Disk management", right-click on the left part (where it's written Disk...), choose Detach VHD (don't check the box), and ok, then unmount USB as normal (from bottom right of the screen).

**PS: if the BT button disappear from settings,** before trying to reinstall it, if you can see it in the "device" panel (with or without a "⚠" on it, or blinking with/without) just try to disable it, and then enable it.